# bash sed processing data with end of line or potentially something else

Tags: bash, sed, whitespace, end-of-line

I have this two types of outputs:

```
UID:474D229F698D494E889D85CEF9303B97:480 f
UID:474D229F698D494E889D85CEF9303B97:480
```

I want to get the 32 char long uid with the 480 at the end of it.
(Note that there is nothing after 480 for the second type of input)
Desired output:

```
474D229F698D494E889D85CEF9303B97:480
474D229F698D494E889D85CEF9303B97:480
```

I am using sed:

```
cat input.txt | sed 's!UID:\(.*\):\([0-9]*\)[\s]*!Captured:\1:\2!'
```

but the output is:

```
Captured:474D229F698D494E889D85CEF9303B97:480 f
Captured:474D229F698D494E889D85CEF9303B97:480
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue?

```
$ awk -F"[: ]" '{print $2":"$3}' file
474D229F698D494E889D85CEF9303B97:480
474D229F698D494E889D85CEF9303B97:480
```

*Explanation*: we define different possible field separators `:` or space . Once the text has been splitted, then we print the 2nd and 3rd field.

`sed` way could be the following:

```
$ sed 's/UID:\([^:]*\):\([^ ]*\).*/Captured:\1:\2/g' file
Captured:474D229F698D494E889D85CEF9303B97:480
Captured:474D229F698D494E889D85CEF9303B97:480
```

*Explanation*: We see the text is based on the pattern `UID:number:number something`. Hence, we get it with `UID:\([^:]*\):\([^ ]*\).*`. With `\( expression \)` we capture the text we need, so that it can be printed later on with `\1`, `\2`...

Comment: Thanks, I will try that, but any way in sed to do it? I have been trying to figure this out for the past 2 hours...

Comment: Sorry that I didn't check it myself, it works, I think my problem was not knowing how to not get the space! Thanks very much!

Comment: Did it solve your problem, @Juto ? Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted if your problem is already solved. All posted ones are fine!

Answer (score 1):

is this ok?

```
grep -oE '[^:]{32}:[^: ]*' file
```

for example:

```
kent$  echo "UID:474D229F698D494E889D85CEF9303B97:480 f
UID:474D229F698D494E889D85CEF9303B97:480"|grep -oE '[^:]{32}:[^: ]*'
474D229F698D494E889D85CEF9303B97:480
474D229F698D494E889D85CEF9303B97:480
```

same idea with **sed**:

```
sed -r 's/.*([^:]{32}:[^: ]*).*/\1/' file
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more? What does [^:] do?

Comment: @Juto `[^:]` means any char except `:`

Comment: echo "UID:474D229F698D494E889D85CEF9303B97:480 f" | sed 's!UID:\(.{32}:[^: ]*\).*!Captured:\1!' is not giving the correct answer...
UID:474D229F698D494E889D85CEF9303B97:480 f

Comment: @Juto did you try my sed command? do you have gnu sed? I had `-r`. I post a command, you test something different, and report not working... :\

Answer (score 0):

In bash, you can use the parameter expansion:

```
s=${s% *}    # Remove everything after space.
echo ${s#*:} # Remove everything before colon.
```

Comment: I am not sure how it will work, as the input might be:

UID:474D229F698D494E889D85CEF9303B97:480 f g

Comment: @Juto: Then just use two percent signs to delete everything after the first space: `s=${s%% *}`.

Comment: nice trick! But I will stick to the sed code, thanks for answering!

Comment: @Juto: Calling a subprocess tends to be slower.